# Visual Studio 2012 not repainting

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012 is not repainting the screen when an exception is raised:
[image]

My normal environment looks like this:
[image]

It doesn't seem to matter whether VS is set to use hardware acceleration or not, or to show the rich client experience or not.

I'm running on Windows 7 Home Premium SP1, 64-bit; VS 2012 Update 2.

Graphics: NVIDIA GeoForce GT 220.

**UPDATE**

I selected Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings, and the problem was resolved.

**UPDATE 2**

The issue has returned.

**UPDATE 3**

I've since upgraded to Windows 8.1, and have not experienced the issue since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such issues are often caused by old graphic card drivers. Try to update them. If you still have issues, go into the VS2012 options and disable the hardware acceleration.

Comment: 1) Windows reports that the drivers (v 311.06) are up to date. 2) As I mentioned in the comments, the issue still arises after disabling hardware acceleration, nor does it help to disable hardware acceleration once the problem is there.

Comment: latest driver is 320.18. Try this driver: http://www.nvidia.com/object/win8-win7-winvista-64bit-320.18-whql-driver.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the "Extensions" running in VS2012, and tried disabling/uninstalling them. HDInsightTools for Azure uninstalled and works great now.  Might be worth checking your extensions?

Comment: I've never used that particular extension.

Comment: It could be any one of the extensions.  A good way to check is to start VS in safe mode without extensions.  If it works fine then it probably is an extension.