# What are the potential causes of Visual Studio 2012 being sluggish?

Tags: windows-7, performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've recently begun to try out MS Visual Studio 2012 (+ NVidia NSight) on two (different) machines running Win7 64bit.

On one machine - actually the one less cluttered with all sort of installed apps - the IDE is very sluggish; keyboard responses take upto 1-1.5 seconds to register (usually less though); dialog boxes open slowly, searches are slow, autocomplete is slow to catch etc.

On another machine I don't see this, so it's not just my subjective impression of the general behavior of VS 2012.

What could be the reasons for this sluggishness? And what can I do about them?

**Notes:**

- There are no repaint problems, like in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/611086/visual-studio-2012-not-repainting).
- My hardware is fast enough.
- Though NSight is installed, I doubt this is what's causing the problem (especially since I'm not doing anything CUDA-related when it manifests).
- It's not the [WebsiteCache crawling issue](http://blog.geocortex.com/2007/12/07/slow-visual-studio-performance-solved/); I made sure it's empty and it's still the same behavior.
- I'm not running an anti-virus or some other evil background processes - except the Windows 7 default services.

Comment: It could be drivers, local VS settings, faulting hardware, anti virus, network issues (including firewall), conflits, partially corrupted installations, partially corrupted OS, a fault with a dependancy (like SQL), the .NET framework version...

Comment: Use the Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Feedback Tool to record and upload the trace to Microsoft: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8a5aac8-0418-4f88-9d34-bdbe2c4cfe72

Answer (score 1):

> I Googled and found one cause for it to be sluggish is if it is accessing too many folders.

http://blog.geocortex.com/2007/12/07/slow-visual-studio-performance-solved/

This is the link that I found.

> "Go to OPTIONS>ENVIRONMENT..under Visual Experience, untick “Use Hardware Graphics Acceleration If Available” for some weird reason your dev environment should loosen / speed straight up."

You could check this one out also?

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion, but this is what's causing my VS2012 sluggishness (see edit).

Comment: Could it be an Anti-virus slowing it down?